# Need help creating a Loop which sleeps a condition, when condition is met it stops until the next action

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm a very beginner at C++ and I'm trying to simulate mouse clicks to a program using C++.

What I'm trying to reach is the following:

While the right mouse button is being pressed:

User right clicks the mouse button (first action)

The application Sleeps for a few milseconds (second action)

It stops sleeping and goes to another condition (third action)

It stays in that condition while the user leaves the mouse click (fourth action)

(Repeat while user clicks again on the right mouse button)

I've tried some alternatives but none of them seems to be working as I expect.
Right now I've tried the following:

```
bool sleep = false;

while (sleep = false) {
    if (MK_RBUTTON) {
        Sleep(100);
        sleep = true;
    }
}
if (sleep = true) {
    (third action);
}
```

Comment: `while (sleep = false) {` note that `=` is assignment `==` is comparison.

Comment: Use `while(!sleep)` instead. A good compiler should warn you about that assignment in a condition.

Comment: I tried it and unfortunately it isn't effecting anything.

Comment: The original code was wrong for the reason I mentioned. Your compiler should have warned you about that. Did you also fix this bug: `if (sleep = true) {`

Comment: Yes I did fix that, it's still not operating the way I want. It does the first actions but won't go past to the second.

Comment: Nothing here has much chance of working. This simply isn't how you respond to user input....

Comment: Thanks for your comment, could you guide me in the best way to make my question work?

Comment: You have it sleeping for 100ms. No action is going to stop that.

Comment: `if (MK_RBUTTON) {` is wrong as well. `MK_RBUTTON` is a constant (0x0002) which will make this statement always true regardless of the state of the mouse. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/wm-rbuttondown

Comment: Look at [`GetAsyncKeyState()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate). The [virtual key code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/virtual-key-codes) for the right mouse button is `VK_RBUTTON` (0x02)

Comment: Normally you'd have a Windows program with a message loop and respond to input events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Remy Lebeau said, GetAsyncKeyState () is a good choice.

I tried to change your code, as follows

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void third_action();
int main()
{
    BOOL sleep = FALSE;
    while (sleep == FALSE)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RBUTTON) < 0)
        {
            //Click RightButton
            Sleep(600);
            sleep = TRUE;
            cout << "Click RightButton" << endl;
        }
        if (sleep == TRUE)
        {
            //third action
            third_action();
            sleep = FALSE;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void third_action()
{
    /*
    Execute your third action here. 
    */
    cout << "third action worked" << endl;
}
```

Comment: The flag is always true when the first if body exits. So the flag can be removed from this code.